# Brute-force attack given multiple hash prefixes

Tags: hash, brute-force-attack, sha-1

<sup>(Context: I'm auditing some code which I suspect to be insecure, but I'd
like to be able to quantify this.)</sup>

Suppose you have a 56-bit secret key (`$secret`), and suppose you have revealed the following information to untrusted parties:

- `$salt` – An easily discovered string
- `$prefix` – The first 32-bits from `sha1($secret + $salt)`

Based on a [previous
question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25448/brute-force-attack-given-small-search-space-and-hash-prefix), an attacker could perform an offline attack using `($salt,$prefix)` as a sieve to narrow the list of possible `$candidates`.  This sieve would reduce the number of candidates from $2^{56}$ to $2^{(56-32)}=2^{24}$.

Now suppose you reveal **multiple** variations of `($salt,$prefix)` (all based on the same `$secret`).  The attacker now has multiple sieves; if applied iteratively, each sieve would further narrow the list of possible `$candidates`.

I'd like to understand how quickly `$candidates` will filter down to the true `$secret`.  For example, if you have two prefixes, how many
`$candidates` should be left?  If you have three prefixes, how many
should be left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two prefixes, say $p_1$ and $p_2$ assuming a well designed hash function, this will give you two lists of possible candidates $L_1,L_2$ each of size roughly $2^{24}.$ The correct value is in both of these lists. It is unlikely to also have spurious candidates since assuming uniformity o relevant variables and fixing, say the list $L_1$, the probability that a random quantity from $\{0,1\}^{56}$ is not in $L_1$ is 
$$
\left(1-\frac{2^{24}}{2^{56}}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{32}}\right),
$$
since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\exp(x).$ Thus
the probability that the $2^{24}$ elements in $L_2$ all fall outside $L_1$ is
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{32}}\right)^{2^{24}}=\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{32}}\right)^{2^{32}}\right]^{2^{-8}}\approx \exp(-2^{-8}) \approx 0.9961
$$
so only in one of about 250 trials would there be a spurious candidate in addition to the correct candidate.

**Edit:** It is widely believed and supported by experimentation that SHA-1 is such a function. Ignore my earlier reference to universal hash functions.

Comment: There's no "big question" here.  SHA-1 is almost certainly such a function -- if it wasn't, it would be horribly broken, and we probably would have noticed this deviation from random from now.  So from the perspective of an attacker, yes, an attack can absolutely treat SHA-1 in this way.  As a result, the bottom line is: 2 candidates are enough to filter down to the true secret.  Universal hash functions are a distraction, and the last paragraph introduces uncertainty that doesn't really exist in practice.

Answer (score 1):

2 candidates are enough that you can (with high probability) uniquely identify the correct secret.  An attacker would still have to enumerate all $2^{56}$ possible values for the secret -- or, on average, about $2^{55}$ values -- to find the right one.  But if the attacker has 2 candidates, then this is enough information that the attacker can recognize when he has the correct value for the secret.

So, yes, your code is insecure.  56-bit security is not enough for most purposes.